# Image of the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$ inside the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, hecke-algebras

**Set-up:**
Consider a finite group $G$ and a subgroup $K$. Given these, we can look at the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$ (here, $1$ is the trivial $1$-dim complex representation of $K$). As a vector space, this is
$$
\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1 := \{f\colon G\to\mathbb{C}\ |\ f(gk)=f(g)\ \forall g\in G,k\in G\}.
$$
We can also define the Hecke algebra
$$
H(G,K) := \{f\colon G\to\mathbb{C}\ |\ f(kgk')=f(g)\ \forall g\in G,k,k'\in K\}.
$$
These both clearly lie in $\mathrm{Fun}(G) := \{f\colon G\to\mathbb{C}\}$, the space of all complex-valued functions on $G$. This space clearly has a basis of delta functions $\{\delta_g\}_{g\in G}$, where each $\delta_g\colon G\to\mathbb{C}$ is given by
$$
\delta_g(x) := \begin{cases} 1,\ &\text{if}\ x=g, \\ 0,\ &\text{else.}\end{cases}
$$
We can endow this vector space with the convolution product
$$
(f\star f')(g) := \sum_{xy=g} f(x)f'(y).
$$
Then $(\mathrm{Fun}(G),\star)$ is a unital associative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

We also have the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with basis elements $\{e_g\}_{g\in G}$ and multiplication $e_ge_h:=e_{gh}$.

Now there's also clearly an algebra isomorphism
$$
\Phi\colon \mathrm{Fun}(G)\to\mathbb{C}[G],\quad \delta_g\mapsto e_g.
$$
**My question is:**
What is the image of $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$ and $H(G,K)$ inside of $\mathbb{C}[G]$?

I believe that $\Phi(\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1) = \mathbb{C}[G]e$ and $\Phi(H(G,K))=e\mathbb{C}[G]e$, where
$$
e := \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} e_k,
$$
which is an idempotent in $\mathbb{C}[G]$. I'm not sure why this is true. How can I see this?

**My answer so far:** I've shown that $\mathbb{C}[G]e\subseteq \Phi(\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1)$.

To see this, take an arbitrary element $(\sum_{g\in G} a_ge_g)e$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]e$, where $a_g\in\mathbb{C}$. Then notice
$$
\bigg(\sum_{g\in G} a_ge_g\bigg)e = \frac{1}{|K|}\bigg(\sum_{g\in G} a_ge_g\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{k\in K}e_k\bigg) = \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_ge_ge_k = \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_ge_{gk}.
$$
Then we apply $\Phi^{-1}$ to see that
$$
\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_ge_{gk} \mapsto \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_g\delta_{gk}.
$$
We wish to show that this lies in $\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$, so we wish to check that this map is invariant under right-multiplication by an element of $K$. To this end, let $g'\in G$, $k'\in K$ and apply $\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_g\delta_{gk}$ to $g'k'$. Note that $\delta_{gk}(g'k')=1$ if and only if $gk=g'k'$ (and $0$ otherwise). This is equivalent to $g=g'k'k^{-1}$. Thus
$$
\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_g\delta_{gk}(g'k') = \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} a_{g'k'k^{-1}}\delta_{g'k'}(g'k') = \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} a_{g'k'k^{-1}}.
$$
Similarly, we apply the map $\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_g\delta_{gk}$ to $g'$. This yields
$$
\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{\substack{g\in G \\ k\in K}} a_g\delta_{gk}(g') = \frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} a_{g'k^{-1}}
$$
Since right-multiplication by an element of $K$ is an automorphism of $G$, we see that $\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} a_{g'k'k^{-1}}=\frac{1}{|K|}\sum_{k\in K} a_{g'k^{-1}}$ which shows that $\mathbb{C}[G]e\subseteq \Phi(\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1)$.

I'm stuck on the reverse subset relation.

For the Hecke algebra, I believe the following result is enough: if $e\neq 0$ is an idempotent in a ring $R$, then $\mathrm{End}_G(eR)$ is ring isomorphic to $eRe$.

**Note:** The above is irrelevant for the Hecke algebra question. I see that the Hecke algebra image follows the same idea as the image of the induced representation.

Comment: Have you tried writing out the conditions? For instance, there's $\delta_h(gk) = \delta_{hk^{-1}}(g)$. There's no magic here--it's either true once the definitions are thrown together or false.

Comment: I've added my work showing that $\mathbb{C}[G]e \subseteq \Phi(\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1)$. I'm stuck on showing the reverse relation. I've shown that if $f = \sum_{g\in G} a_g e_g \in \mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$ then $a_{gk}=a_g$ for all $g\in G$ and $k\in K$, but I can't see how this may be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your attempt so far, I'll do the other direction of the first statement in a similar style. There are of course many ways to organize it.

Claim: $\Phi(\mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1) \subseteq \mathbb{C}[G]e$.

Idea: if $x = ye$, then $xe = ye^2 = ye = x$, so $x$ itself will be a "witness" that it is in $\mathbb{C}[G]e$.

Proof: Let $f \in \mathrm{Ind}_K^G 1$, so $f \colon G \to \mathbb{C}$ where $f(gk) = f(g)$ for all $g \in G, k \in K$. Write $f = \sum_{g \in G} f(g) \delta_g$, so $\Phi(f) = \sum_{g \in G} f(g) e_g$. Then

\begin{align*}
  \Phi(f)e &= \frac{1}{|K|} \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{g \in G} f(g) e_{gk} \\
  &= \frac{1}{|K|} \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{g \in G} f(gk^{-1}) e_g \\
  &= \frac{1}{|K|} \sum_{k \in K} \sum_{g \in G} f(g) e_g \\
  &= \sum_{g \in G} f(g) e_g \\
  &= \Phi(f),
\end{align*}

where the second equality comes from reindexing the inner sum using $g \mapsto gk^{-1}$. $\Box$